VBA copy cell in one sheet to another empty row when next cell is blank
I am able to copy row from one sheet to another sheet when cell in Column E of the first sheet is blank :
Sub CopyToAnotherSheet()

   Dim LastRow As Long

   'Find last used row in a Column A of Sheet1
   With Worksheets("CHECK DB")
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
   End With

   'Find first row where values should be posted in Sheet2
   With Worksheets("Descript")
      j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
   End With
   
   'Paste each row that contains "Mavs" in column A of Sheet1 into Sheet2
   For i = 2 To LastRow
       With Worksheets("CHECK DB")
           If .Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
               .Rows(i).COPY Destination:=Worksheets("Descript").Range("A" & j)
               j = j + 1
           End If
       End With
   Next i
   
End Sub

how can I change this code just to copy values from Column D when value in column E is blank, not the entire row, can you help me?

Give this a try:
Sub CopyToAnotherSheet()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim j As Long

'Find last used row in Column D of Sheet1
With Worksheets("CHECK DB")
   LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Find first row where values should be posted in Sheet2
With Worksheets("Descript")
   j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With

'Copy values from Column D of Sheet1 into Column A of Sheet2 if Column E is blank
For i = 2 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("CHECK DB")
        If .Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then ' Check if Column E is blank
            Worksheets("Descript").Cells(j, 1).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value ' Copy value from Column D to Column A in Sheet2
            j = j + 1
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub


Of course, after two hours of breaking my head, you just fixed it in 3 mins....thank you!
What if I would like to CONCATENATE (B, " ", D) and copy it to Col A of second sheet?

Actually I just figured it out, lol
= .Cells(i, 2).Value & " " & .Cells(i, 4)

Don't feel bad at all. That is the, I think 7th?, try. That's how we get better.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
